# laravel5 set cookie on ajax call

Tags: ajax, laravel, cookies

When the user clicks add to cart I create an new cart and add the product to the cookie of the user. But how do I set the cookie on an ajax response. Im trying:

```
//set the values for the view make
$cartId = 'someval i set earlyer'
$cookie = Cookie::forever('cartid', $cartId);

$currentCart = Cart::findOrFail($cartId);

$items = CartItem::where('cart_id','=',$currentCart->id)->get();

//this function also check the $request on a valid cookie
$total = $this->calculateCartTotal($request);
return Response::json(View::make('front.cart.render',compact('items', 'total'))->withCookie($cookie)->render());
```

But the value is never set, I tryd refreshing the page but there is still no cookie for cartid. How can I set a cookie for an ajax reponse

Comment: What's your JavaScript code? Cookies are automatically sent by the browser with AJAX requests. Are you sure the request is being sent successfully and a correct response is received?

Comment: @Bogdan Yes i am sure, i give data back which i put on specifi places (like total)

Comment: Please post the headers passed by the XHR request, as well as the ones received with the response.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return Response::json(
    View::make('front.cart.render',compact('items', 'total'))->render()
)->withCookie($cookie);
```

`rendor` belongs to `View`

`withCookie` belongs to `Response`

Check Response headers.

`Set-Cookie:cartid=...`